# Reduced determinant to calculate coefficient of $x$

Tags: determinant

**Question:**

> Calculate coefficient of $x$ in $$f(x)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
> x & (1+\sin x)^3 & \cos x \\
> 1 & \ln(1+x) & 2 \\ 
> x^2 & 1+x^2 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}$$

**My attempt:**

I know how to do such types of problems. I calculated $f'(x)$ by splitting the given determinant columnwise, and noted that the coefficient of $x$ in $f(x)$ is simply $f'(0)$. I also got the correct answer ($=-2$).

I am curious about the method given in my book. They say that:

> Coefficient of $x$ in $f(x)$ is same as the coefficient of $x$ in $g(x)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
> x & 1 & 1 \\
> 1 & x & 2 \\ 
> x^2 & 1 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}$

I do not understand how they arrived at the matrix in $g(x)$. I tried relating this to Taylor series, since that is probably the only way to convert $\ln$ or $\sin$ into a polynomial function of $x$, but it did not make sense since:

1. these taylor series only work for $x\to0$, while here we have $\text{Domain}_{f(x)}=\{x:x>-1\}$, and
2. they retained $x$ from $\ln(1+x)$, but dismissed the $3x$ from $(1+\sin x)^3$, though both are having the same degree $1$

I don't know of any other possible method to arrive at $g(x)$ from $f(x)$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't quite understand what "coefficient of $x$" means. Do you mean the coefficient of $x$ in the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x=0$ or something else? Would you consider "coefficient of $x$" in, say $h(x)=x\ln(1+x)$, as $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: @Jack You're right, that confused me as well, but eventually I have no clue. I have stated everything as is. Am sorry if the question given in the textbook itself is pretty meaningless :(

Comment: What textbook/chapters are you reading? The context around the question may help to clarify it. If it is in the second case, then the answer is quite simple by observing a row expansion of the determinant.

Comment: @Jack Chapter is on determinants in an [algebra book](https://www.cengage.co.in/category/test-prep/jee-advanced/mathematics/course/mathematics-for-joint-entrance-examination-jee-advanced-algebra-ma) There's not much context though :/ The other problems around this question are about other properties of determinants.

Comment: The book is in fact an exam prep book in engineering, as the first point of the linked book suggests.  IMHO, the ability to estimate/control error (using Taylor's expansion) is an important "aptitude for the engineering field"

Comment: @GNUSupporter Indeed, that's true. The book has multiple examples of problems which require slightly advanced manipulation of geometry or calculus, either of which is not covered under algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Use small-O notation.

\begin{align}
x^2 &= o(x) \\
\sin(x) &= x + o(x) \\
\ln(1+x) &= x + o(x) \\
\cos(x) &= 1 + o(x)
\end{align}

Substitute them into $f(x)$.

$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \det\begin{pmatrix}
x & (1+\sin x)^3 & \cos x \\
1 & \ln(1+x) & 2 \\ 
x^2 & 1+x^2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \det\begin{pmatrix}
x & (1+x+o(x))^3 & 1+o(x) \\
1 & x+o(x) & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 1+o(x) & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \det\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1+3x+o(x) & 1+o(x) \\
1 & x+o(x) & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 1+o(x) & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

Delete the $o(x)$ from the above determinant to get
$$h(x)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1+3x & 1 \\
1 & x & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Remarks: I wrote $o(x)$ instead of $x^2$ in the lower-left corner since it has no role in the calculation of coefficient of $x$.

You might notice a difference in the top entry $1$ in $g(x)$ and $1+3x$ in $h(x)$, but since the determinant is multilinear,

$$\begin{aligned}
h(x) &= \begin{vmatrix}
x & 1+3x & 1 \\
1 & x & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
x & 1 & 1 \\
1 & x & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
+ \begin{vmatrix}
x & 3x & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=\begin{vmatrix}
x & 1 & 1 \\
1 & x & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
+(-3x) \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 0
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=\begin{vmatrix}
x & 1 & 1 \\
1 & x & 2 \\ 
o(x) & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
+(-3x)(-2o(x)) \\
&= g(x) + o(x).
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Requesting contextual definition: small-O definition is just a fancy term for the negligible terms in a taylor series. Am I correct?

Comment: When I was undergrad, I used to say so, but in research papers, they are a convenient tool to simplify expansions.

Comment: (+1) for validating @farruhota's answer. In the case they proposes, $o(x)=1$, and your second last step makes it clear that ignoring the extra term $3x$ at the matrix position (1,2) can result in error.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is valid. Consider $f(x)$ with $a_{31}=1$ instead of $x^2$. Then the coefficient will be $3$ and $g(x)$ with $a_{12}=1+3x$ will give $3$, however the book's suggested $g(x)$ will not.

Comment: (+1) for a clever observation. I will wait for a bit longer before an answer acceptance, till someone comes up with a proper application guideline for this technique, i.e., exactly, when and how it can be applied.